# Como alterar LINK de uma imagem por CSS

Tags: css

Estou editando um site onde só tenho acesso a uma área para inserir CSS. E tenho uma imagem padrão com um link, consegui trocar a imagem usando só o css, porém, gostaria de saber se há como (mesmo sabendo que é totalmente contra os padrões web) eu modificar o link dessa imagem através de CSS. Ressaltando que só posso inserir linhas de CSS.

Comment: Como assim? Você quer alterar a imagem se o mouse passar por cima da área, por exemplo?

Comment: Não não, na verdade é bem estranho mesmo. Eu só posso inserir css, e tenho uma imagem com href="http://exemplo.com". Consegui mudar essa imagem usando só o css que tenho acesso, porém gostaria de trocar esse href para href="http://novo.com" usando somente css também.

Comment: Infelizmente isso é impossivel, vide resposta.

Answer (score 4):

Via CSS tu não vai conseguir passar valores para um atributo `<a href="">` no html. Tu só vai conseguir fazer isso através do HTML ou via JavaScript.

Comment: pois é, estava com medo dessa resposta hahaha